# Adding up the sum of the numbers that are printed

Tags: c#

I am new at C# and I have a simple question to ask. This is my code and I would like to makes some changes to it by adding up the sum of the numbers that are entered. How do I go about doing that?

Example:
User input 5.
Output:
1
2
3
4
5

What I want to achieve is to find out the sum of all of the numbers that are entered.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace Q2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = 0;
            Console.Write("Enter a number:");
            num=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 1; i <=num; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int num = 0;
int sum = 0;
Console.Write("Enter a number:");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
 Console.WriteLine(i);
 sum += i;               
}
Console.WriteLine("Sum is"+sum);
```

Comment: Can you explain how sum += i works? I do not quite get it.

Comment: have you heard of assignment operators? here sum += i means sum = sum +i;

Comment: I see. Thank you, I will read more about assignment operators. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add it after the for loop
`sum = ((num+1)*(num)/2)`

Answer (score 0):

Less effective, because loop numbers twice, but maybe little bid more readable

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number:");
    int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, num);

    var allNumbers = string.Join(" ", numbers);
    Console.WriteLine(allNumbers);

    Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0}", numbers.Sum())
}
```